# What is the fastest and most efficient way on iOS to downscale a HD video to SD?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

I have a video which is represented as AVURLAsset. It comes from Camera Roll and is at full resolution.

Now if I only need it with 380 pixels width, what would be the fastest and most efficient way to get a downsampled copy of the video?

Is `AVAssetExportSession` the way to go? It also looks like [AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009513) only works with presets. But in this case I want to specify custom pixel dimensions.

> "An AVAssetExportSession object transcodes the contents of an AVAsset
>   source object to create an output of the form described by a specified
>   export preset."

Or must I look at other classes in AVFoundation? Or other frameworks even?

Answer (score 0):

AVMutableVideoComposition has a renderSize property or AVAssetWriter/WriterInput has an ability to resize frame as you want, as well as other tweaks are possible (you are supplying output size/settings in dictionary), but it comes with necessity to set the whole stuff up (asset reader, feeding frames etc.). If you find better solution, let me know :)